# Cypress: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cypress, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy my cypress tests using cloud build, however, I keep getting the following error in cloud build.

`Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my docker file

```
FROM cypress/browsers:node13.8.0-chrome81-ff75

WORKDIR /root

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "cy:run:chrome"]
```

and here is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
    # Build image  
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/app-trick/cypress-tests', './']
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      args: ['push', 'gcr.io/app-trick/cypress-tests']          

    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
      args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'cypress-tests'
      - '--image'
      - 'gcr.io/app-trick/cypress-tests'
      - '--region'
      - 'us-east4'
      - '--platform'
      - 'managed'
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "cypress_nid",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "cy:open": "npx cypress open --port $PORT",
    "cy:run": "npx cypress run --port $PORT",
    "cy:run:chrome": "npx cypress run --browser chrome --port $PORT",
    "cy:run:firefox": "npx cypress run --browser firefox --port $PORT",
    "cy:run:record": "npx cypress run --record --port $PORT"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^4.11.0",
    "cypress-promise": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "D": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `package.json` where the `cy:run:chrome` script is defined?

Comment: @DustinIngram I have added my package.json file now

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `EXPOSE 8080` in your `Dockerfile`.

Instead, you need to adhere to the [Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract) by listening for requests on `$PORT`. This will most often be `8080`, but you shouldn't assume it.

This means you need to pass the [`--port`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-port-lt-port-gt) argument to `cypress run`, and use the `$PORT` environment variable, so your script would have something like:

```
"cy:run:chrome": "npx cypress run --browser chrome --port $PORT",
```

Comment: silly question but where am I actually defining the value for the $PORT?

Comment: It comes from Cloud Run, you don't define it.

Comment: I updated the package.json to include the port. Please see the updated json above

Comment: Looking at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run, this says "Runs Cypress tests to completion". This doesn't seem like something that is starting a service that can respond to web traffic. Can you also include the deploy command you're using? Why are you trying to deploy this to Cloud Run?